# how do you make a <p> tag remain under a <div> while using jquery .hover?

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm trying to get a div of a picture hover and reveal text underneath it (the divs with the images in them need to be next to each other) Currently the text in the

tag that im trying to reveal only shows up next to the div. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**here is the css**

```
.art-thumb{
margin-left:30px;
margin-top:15px;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
.artist-statement{
height:2em;
width:200px;
display:none;
}
```

**This is the html.erb**

```
<div class = "projects">
<%@followers.each do |display|%>
    <%=display.name %>
<% end %>
<%= render 'follow_form' %>

<%@galleries.each do |gallery|%>
    <%if gallery.art_works.first && gallery.art_works.first.art.url %>
    <div class = "art-thumb">
        <p><%= gallery.title %></p>
        <%= link_to image_tag(gallery.art_works.first.art.thumb.url), gallery_path(gallery) %>     
    </div>
    <div class="artist-statement">
        <%= gallery.artist_statement %>
    </div>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

**and here is the js**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
//move the thumbnail up
$('.art-thumb').hover(
    function(){
        console.log('it works!');
        $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'50px'},function(){
           $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideDown();
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'0'},function(){
           $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideUp();
        });
    }
    );
            console.log('it knows it should move');

 });
```

**Here is the js fiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/15/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/44/) is how I fixed it. First you need to wrap your `div` and `p` inside a `wrapper`. Place `float: left` in that wrapper and everything will fine

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement1</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement3</p>
</div>

.art-thumb {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    background-color:red;

    margin:35px;
}
.artist-statement {
    display:none;
    position: relative;

}

.wrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

Now you only need to modify a little to make your `div` and `p` arrange inside `wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each of the thumb/caption pairs in a div.

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb">
    </div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb">
    </div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="art-thumb">
    </div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

Add the margin to the wrapper elements:

```
.wrapper{ height: 60px; width: 60px; position: relative; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;}
.art-thumb{height:60px;width:60px;background-color:red;position: absolute}
.artist-statement{ display: none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: -1}
```

### JS

**Updated Javascript** (note: if you want the movement of the box and reveal of the captions to be in sync, run slideUp() on the caption elements concurrently with the animation of the thumbnail, not as a callback function after it completes.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    //move the thumbnail up
    $('.art-thumb').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'50px'},function(){
                $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideDown();
            });
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'0'},function(){
                  $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideUp();
            });
        }
        );

});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/51/

Comment: Thank you very much! the jsfiddle you sent doesnt seem to be revealing the text though?

Comment: If you want to reveal the text at the same time the thumbnail moves then run the slideUp/SlideDown function right after the thumbnail animation, rather than as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement1</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="art-thumb"></div>
    <p class="artist-statement">artist statement3</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    float:left;
}

.art-thumb
{
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:35px 35px 10px;
}

.artist-statement
{
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/veHq3/57/